# Can you have an open interval over the set of natural numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

Can you have an open interval for instance, over the set of natural numbers? Wouldn't every open interval on the natural numbers simply be another way of writing a closed interval over the naturals?

Do the concepts of "open" and "closed" intervals only make sense for "continuous stuff"?

How do "open" and "closed"  intervals generalize for non-'numerical' stuff?

What is professional mathematical terminology for "stuff"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set  An open set in the reals is open in the subspace topology over the naturals.  But any set in the naturals is closed -- so they are clopen sets.  The space is totally disconnected and has dimension zero.

Comment: Let us just take a moment to appreciate the brilliance of the term '_clopen_'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer:
Let $\mathbb R$ be endowed with the usual topology of open sets generated by open intervals (a,b). The subset topology on $\mathbb N\subset\mathbb R$ has as open sets all open sets in $\mathbb R$ intersected with $\mathbb N$. Same for closed sets. This is means any subset of $\mathbb N$ is both closed and open (sometimes known as clopen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw) in this topology. This is also known as the discrete topology. So a range, or interval, in the natural numbers such as $\{i,i+1,i+2,\dots,i+k\}=[i,i+k]\cap\mathbb N=(i-1/2,i+k+1/2)\cap\mathbb N$ is closed (and open) in the usual topology associated with the natural numbers.

Comment: That helped a lot! Could you also edit it to address some of the other questions in my question?

Comment: This is the unanswered question in my original question: 

What is professional mathematical terminology for "stuff"? "Topological space"?

Comment: I would say that the way that closed and open intervals generalize from the real line to subsets of the real line (such as natural numbers) would be through the subset topology. That is, a closed interval in the subset is a closed interval on the real line intersected with that subset. Same for open intervals. And I guess "stuff" is a topology and the usual way to extend a topology from a larger space with a canonical topology (like $\mathbb R$ with open sets generated by open intervals) to a subset is the subset topology.